# Non-scriptable foreign key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

This is the problem I am facing:

I have a table with several foreign keys. One of them does not get scripted when I script the table as Create To New Query window in SSMS but the rest of them do. It also doesn't appear in Keys folder in Object Explorer.

The only way it appears is when I open Design View for the table in SSMS, right-click on Design window and select Relationships. Then it shows up as expected (together with the rest of the foreign keys).

I am fairly confident I created this key via SSMS Design wizard.

The reason it came to my attention is that I ran Database Schema Compare in Visual Studio 2015 to deploy my changes and it didn't show this as a difference either (Design in Visual Studio doesn't show it, same for scripting the table Visual Studio). However, I remembered setting up this foreign key and looked into this to find that something is not quite right with it.

How can this be explained/avoided?

Comment: Is the foreign key that isn't scripting with the table a column in the table that is referenced by another table, rather than referencing another table? If so, then the foreign key would be scripted by the referencing table rather than the parent/source table.

Comment: @SqlZim: I am not sure what the difference is. The FK that isn't scripting is a column of (int, not null) type. It is also a PK in the table being scripted. It serves as a primary key in another table. This is 1 to (0 or 1) relationship.

Comment: When you script the other table, does the foreign key you are looking for get scripted?

Comment: It can be avoided by never using the SSMS Design Wizard.   Can you add a screenshot of what you are seeing that makes you think the FK is there at all?

Comment: @SqlZim: yes, when I script the other table foreign key I am looking for gets scripted.

Comment: @TabAlleman: sorry I am not able to post a screenshot. It shows up in Relationships list.

Comment: a foreign key is a constraint, and that constraint exists on the table that references another table (not the table being referenced). So that would explain why you aren't seeing it when you are scripting the parent table that is being referenced by that constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes, when I script the other table foreign key I am looking for gets
>   scripted

That is the answer.  The FK exists on the other table.  Not the table you are looking at.   That's why it doesn't get scripted.

Comment: I feel like an idiot now. That being said, it also shows as a Relationship on the other table. Wouldn't it make sense for SSMS to only show it as a Relationship in one place to be consistent?

Comment: I guess enough people want to see Relationships in SSMS regardless of which side of the relationship the table is on.